# How and why did limerence come to be idolized as it is in modern Western society?

Tags: united-states, social-history, cultural-history, contemporary-history, modern

Limerence - the involuntary, infatuated state that has been romanticized as love.

Before you read in, the basics of my question have to do with the historical forces that have shaped the modern popular conception that limerence is a virtue, a necessity for a full life, etc. - romanticized beyond reason.

I am not a history buff, but this topic is intensely interesting to me.

To my understanding, limerence did not become idolized to the point that it currently is until recently. Nowadays, it is a major theme of many movies and novels, wherein characters are unfulfilled without it. In popular culture it is held up as one of the most important things to experience in life, perhaps even a virtue. It is an ideal to which we should aspire. It is an acceptable and often used reason for marriage - which, as I understand it, is not how marriages generally used to work. There is no end to the number of Nicholas Sparks-style imagery, movies, novels, etc.

All of this despite the fact that science has high confidence that it is a transient phenomenon lasting on average 18-36 months.

Of course people have always experienced limerence, but to my understanding it was not such a central aspect of societies throughout history.

Perhaps I am fully incorrect in my assumptions; if so, please explain! Please don't downvote the question into oblivion. Or if you do, please leave a comment about why. I'm really interested in the historical forces that have shaped the modern popular conception of limerence to being a necessary component in a full, happy life.

If I were to hazard a guess, it is that people often don't have any better criteria to choose mates nowadays, and limerence is a very strong force. Even if that were true, it doesn't explain how the situation got this way.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I blame the Russians - I remember being stunned by Turgenev's "Torrents of Spring" and raging in frustration at *Anna Karenina*. If only we'd stuck to our Austen and Dickens...

Comment: Lots of assertions made and very little to back them up. Can you prove that limerence is "romanticized beyond reason"? That limerence is only present in modern western society? Provide some links to  peer-reviewed scientific papers that proves this is a "transient phenomenon" perhaps?

Comment: @bruised reed: Russians? How about Tristan and Iseault?

Comment: I'm always wary of questions that demand that I don't downvote as this is an acknowledgment of the weakness of the question by the asker. I'm not an expert on world cinema or literature but from what I have seen and read, I'd say that limerence or infatuated love was common trope across the globe.

Comment: @SteveBird I have been downvoted a few times on other sites without any explanation. I think the question is pretty strong: if I'm wrong about the whole idea, please tell me instead of downvoting the question.

Comment: @KillingTime that's sort of the point. I'd like more information about how it came to be this way, if this is how it is. In regards to its length, I'm not going to copy the citations section out of Wikipedia, nor the citations out of the books that it cites.

Comment: @SteveBird I don't think it's opinion-based if it is about peer-reviewed science. I'm asking about the history of a phenomenon that has been researched and peer reviewed, and how that history has affected the modern day. I'm not sure how to get less opinion-based since that, especially since most history textbooks contain around the same level of opinion, as must happen in to interpret history beyond simple facts.

Comment: I voted to close the question because it seems too broad, but I understand other options chosen (primarily opinion-based and unclear what you are asking). Also, there's an awful lot of rant in your question.

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave One of the expectations of the History SE is that you [cite any non-trival assertions](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-i-get-a-downvote/633#633) that your post includes. This question fails in that respect. You're expecting people to answer "how did we get here" without providing any proof that we're "here" at all.

Comment: One thing missed in the "how marriages used to work" is that when marriages used to work that way, it was because women were typically regarded as property, and married off to the highest bidder.

Comment: Another overlooked factor is that while you say "limerence" is a "transient phenomenon lasting on average 18-36 months", a quick search finds that the average (American, at least) engagement is 14.5 months, and the average length of dating before engagement runs 29-40 months (depending on age).  So given that 14.5 + 29 = 43.5, it would seem that "limerence" generally has a good chance of running its course before marriage.  And this doesn't even factor in the sizable fraction of couples who live together before (possibly) marrying.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the dominant topic in the arts, at least in the Western art. Some say that this is a recent phenomenon, but in fact it is present in the Western art
from the very beginning of its modern genres, precisely from the times of the Roman empire. In the oldest surviving novel, Aethiopica by Heliodorus (3d or 4th century ad), this is the main topic. It does not seem to be prominent or even present in the earlier literature. But this particular novel contains in the nutshell all plots of the later romance novels up to Hollywood movies.

I have no sufficient knowledge of Chinese or Indian classical cultures, but I conjecture that this feature was originally present only in Western culture.

Comment: Thank you! Excellent information. I shall revise my question to be more specific about its role in marriage.

Comment: Re earlier literature, I think one could argue that it provides the motivation for the Illiad, no?

Comment: You postulate that something is only present in “Western” culture, but while admitting lack of “sufficient knowledge” of other cultures (of which Chinese and Indian were only a few).

Comment: I’m not going to claim that every culture places equal emphasis on (purportedly) transient romantic love, but some ancient cross-cultural examples are the story of Liang Shanbo and Zhu Yingtai from China, or the story of Kintu and Nambi from Uganda (the latter of which even has religious significance).

Comment: @jamesqf: If you analyse Iliad, (the text, not the Hollywood movies based on it), you see that this motive is absent there: there is nothing about "love", as it is understood in the later European literature.